# Issue of Set Download File name from controller MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller, controller

I tried to get and download file from server local folder to client side. But When I tried to download(also download operation is successfully), Downloaded file's name is set automatically Action Name. How can I change downloaded file name ?

MyController:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public PhysicalFileResult MYACTIONDOWNLOAD(string filePathAndName)
{
    string downloadPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"C:\", filePathAndName);
    string filesMimeType = MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(filePathAndName);
     return new PhysicalFileResult(downloadPath, filesMimeType); 
}
```

client side(view script):

```
<a target="_blank" href="(my website www root url)/MYPROJECTNAME/MYCONTROLLERNAME/MYACTIONDOWNLOAD?filePathAndName=\\192.168.X.X\MYREMOTEDISC-1\MYDOCUMENTS\SCHOOL\10012021_1023350.docx"></a>
```

when I clicked download operation is okey but downloaded file name is **MYACTIONDOWNLOAD.docx**
I want to change file name.

Comment: Hi @hkyaaa，any update?Have you try my solution?

Comment: I tried all belows comments but I couldnt work then I tried client side view change file name, becaue this <a> element create dynamically based on datatable row data and I recognized that then I tried and reach my goal finally:                                        
  `data: "fileName",  render: '<a target="_blank" href="(my website www root url)/MYPROJECTNAME/MYCONTROLLERNAME/MYACTIONDOWNLOAD?filePathAndName=\\192.168.X.X\MYREMOTEDISC-1\MYDOCUMENTS\SCHOOL\10012021_1023350.docx" download="'+data+'" style="text-decoration:underline;"></a>'`

Answer (score 2):

You can just change your code like following:

```
return new PhysicalFileResult(downloadPath, filesMimeType) { FileDownloadName = "Test.doc"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of path use

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("your path" )
```

and then

```
return File(bytes, mimetype,"name you want" );
```

Comment: Should I change my method's return type ?

Comment: if it is not really needed then you should change to FileResult and for your information  PhysicalFileResult is derieved from FileResult which is return type of File method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method instead.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string path)
    {
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        string webRootPath = _HostEnvironment.WebRootPath; 
        var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath + path);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(uploads, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(uploads).ToLowerInvariant();
        return File(memory, "application/octet-stream", "any file name");
    }
```

_HostEnvironment.WebRootPath will be give the absolute path of the server. If that comes from your URL then you can avoid this.

Comment: _HostEnvironment couldnt find and using, actually visual stuido suggest to "using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" but still cant solve my problem.

Comment: actually it comes from 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal; and add it with Dependency Injection on your controller's constructor. Actually _HostEnvironment here is the private field for HostingEnvironment coming from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal. Could you share the result you get after this?

Comment: Else you can use it in this way as well
var memory = new MemoryStream();
            HostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();
            string webRootPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;